# Homebrew install issues

Tags: node.js, npm, homebrew, yeoman

I am having some trouble with brew installs. So I have done the following:

Uninstalled homebrew with:

> $ rm -rf /usr/local/Cellar /usr/local/.git && brew cleanup

---

Reinstalled homebrew with:

> $ ruby -e "$(curl -fsSkL raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/go/install)"

---

> $ brew update
>
> Already up-to-date.
>
> $ brew doctor
>
> Your system is raring to brew.

---

Try running any install & I get the following output:

> $ brew install node
>
> Error: Permission denied - /Library/Caches/Homebrew/Formula/node.brewing

---

What is going on here? This is also giving me issues with using npm and yeoman which I'd really like to use :(

Comment: @lenybernard I understand the install script location may have changed, but the proper response here is a comment, not an edit of the original question.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Did you perhaps install brew with an other user, or with `sudo` previously?

Check the permissions of `/Library/Caches/Homebrew`, and force it to be writable for your user, by either changing its owner, or its permissions.

You might also try to uninstall with something like https://gist.github.com/1173223 and try the install again.

Comment: /Library/Cashes/Homebrew has me listed as the owner. It has the following as my permissions: 'drwxrwxrwx'. About to try the gist.

Comment: also check all the way down to node.brewing.  maybe you used `sudo brew install node` before?

Comment: Fantastic, just had to "chown -R". Thanks!

Comment: `sudo chown -R \`whoami\` /Library/Caches/Homebrew/`

Comment: You might also need `sudo chown -R root /usr/local/bin/brew`.

Answer (score 0):

This thing told me to tell you to update that install command to

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```