# How can I see the current value of my $PATH variable on OS X?

Tags: macos, bash, path, environment-variables, homebrew

> $ $PATH

returns:

> -bash: /usr/local/share/npm/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:~/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin: No such file or directory

This seems quite ugly and might be [giving me issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14616981/homebrew-install-issues) with getting Homebrew up and running as well.

Answer (score 213, accepted):

You need to use the command `echo $PATH` to display the PATH variable or you can just execute `set` or `env` to display all of your environment variables.

By typing `$PATH` you tried to run your PATH variable contents as a command name.

Bash displayed the contents of your path any way.  Based on your output the following directories will be searched in the following order:

```
/usr/local/share/npm/bin
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin
/usr/local/bin
/usr/local/sbin
~/bin
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
/usr/local/bin
/opt/X11/bin
/usr/local/git/bin
```

To me this list appears to be complete.

Comment: Thank you. I would greatly appreciate if you could checkout the other question listed. But thanks for the clarification on $PATH.

Comment: It's worth noting that the string that is returned from `echo $PATH` (or, in this case, just `$PATH`) acts more like an array, where each colon ("`:`") is a separator between each entry. It's helpful to imagine a space (or, a new line) at each `:`.

Answer (score 55):

To list out the paths as individual lines, you could use:

```
echo "${PATH//:/\n}"
```

Answer (score 46):

By entering `$PATH` on its own at the command prompt, you're trying to *run* it. This isn't like Windows where you can get your path output by simply typing `path`.

If you want to see what the path is, simply echo it:

```
echo $PATH
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the command:

```
 echo $PATH
```

and you will see all path:

> /Users/name/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@pe/bin:/Users/name/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@global/bin:/Users/sasha/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/bin:/Users/sasha/.rvm/bin:

Answer (score -3):

for MacOS, make sure you know where the GO install

```
export GOPATH=/usr/local/go
PATH=$PATH:$GOPATH/bin
```